# Resources for UnrealScript

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

Now that the [Unreal Development Kit](http://www.udk.com/index.html) is out and free to use by anyone, I am pretty excited to try it out. My understanding is that the programming is done through scripting in [UnrealScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrealscript), I am wondering if any of you guys know of any **good** articles, tutorials, books, and references for Unreal Script or the Unreal Development Kit.

### Documentation

- [UnrealScript Reference for Unreal Engine 3](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/UnrealScriptReference.html)
- [UnrealScript at UnrealWiki](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:UnrealScript)

### Tools

- [nFringe - Visual Studio editor and debugger for UnrealScript](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:nFringe)

  - [Setting up an nFringe UDK project](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:nFringe:UnrealScript:UdkProjects)
  - [Testing: New support for building scripts with nFringe](http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?p=27238597)
- [WOTgreal - the editing tool for the Unreal® Engine](http://www.wotgreal.com/)

  - The current development version supports UDK
- [UnCodeX - UnrealScript Swiss Army Knife](http://uncodex.elmuerte.com/)

### Tutorials

- [Chimeric - Coding tutorials](http://chimeric.beyondunreal.com/tutorials.php)

### Video Tutorials

- [3D Buzz Video Tutorials](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/VideoTutorials.html#Unreal%20Engine%203%20Video%20Tutorials)

Comment: I'm converting a UT3 project to UDK and I've been posting several compiler errors I've run into, and the solutions. Check the unrealscript tag and look for my questions. My hope is that they become top Google results and SO becomes a sort of database for UT3->UDK conversion compile errors!

Comment: If you google some more specific things you will find tutorials by indie developers and such, I only recall this page:
http://www.moug-portfolio.info/category/tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't that much out there, the best way to learn is by looking through the source code of UT3 and mods for it. I'd recommend exporting script from the .u files (don't have a link on me at the moment) so that you can see the code from all of the Make Something Unreal Contest mods.

Download the latest UT3 source code here:
http://udn.epicgames.com/Files/UT3/Mods/UT3ScriptSource_1.5.rar

There's also a handy program called "UnCodeX" that makes it easy to trace unrealscript code.
[uncodex.elmuerte.com](http://uncodex.elmuerte.com)

There's an option for html output too, which I have a copy of (although it's not the absolute latest version, it's pretty recent) on my site: http://www.aaronash.com/ut3/UT3_UnCodex_v1.3/

The UT3 source code should be plenty for you to learn off of however, good luck!